# При нажатии на Enter PyCharm добавляет скобки

Tags: python, pycharm

```
r = requests.get(url=url)
headers = ''
```

При нажатии на <kbd>Enter</kbd> находясь между кавычками PyCharm редактирует код:

```
headers = (''
           '')
```

Дублирует кавычки + ставит скобки.
Кто знает как убрать?

Comment: Что ты хочешь получить нажимая на энтер между кавычками?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы IDE не дублировала "" и не ставила скобки, а просто переносила строку и курсор на следующую строчку:
headers = '
'
Переустановил Pycharm, сбросил все настройки - все равно не работает. В VSC обычное нормальное поведение при нажатие Enter - обычный перенос строки с элементами после курсора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm старается *помочь вам избежать ошибок:*

1. **Почему ставит скобки?**

   Потому, что в Питоне невозможно просто без упреждения разорвать то, что должно быть в одной строке кода, на 2 или более строк:

   ```
   while a < 2 and
         b > 5:             # неправильно — синтаксическая ошибка
   ```

   Но это возможно сделать с соответствующим сигналом интерпретатору Питона:

   - символом продолжения команды `\`:

     ```
     while a < 2 and   \
           b > 5:         # теперь правильно — то же самое как  while a < 2 and b > 5:
     ```

   или

   - тем, что затем не окончена начальная скобка (`(` или `[` или `{`) — тогда Питон ждет ее окончания обратной скобкой (`)` или `]` или `}`):

     ```
     fruits = [апельсин,
               яблоко,
               ананас,
              ]            # правильно
     ```

     Значит, что в первом примере мы можем для продолжения команды использовать вместо символа продолжения `\` **излишние скобки**:

     ```
     while (a < 2 and   
            b > 5):        # тоже правильно
     ```

     *Именно такой, по моему более красивый подход, использует PyCharm в вашем случае, когда вы еще не окончили команду и хотите ее продолжить в следующей строке кода.*
2. **Почему дублирует кавычки / апострофы?**

   Это не дублирование, а *окончание первой части строки и подготовка на вторую.*

   Объясню:

   В Питоне невозможно строку в кавычках или апострофах продолжать на следующей строке кода (для этого нужно применить **тройку** кавычек / апострофов:

   ```
   'Имя
   Отечество'               # не возможно — синтаксическая ошибка



   '''Имя
    Отечество'''            # правильно
   ```

   PyCharm, чтобы избежать ошибки, правильно предполагает, что вы вашу (однострочную) строку хотите продолжить на следующей строке кода.

   Для этого он использует синтаксис для соединения строковых литералов в одну строку тем, что они просто запишутся возле себя:

   ```
   'Какая '   'красивая '   'девушка'     # то же самое как 'Какая красивая девушка'
   ```

   Вы пока после апострофа ничего не написали — значит, вы хотите продолжить *пустую строку*.

   Для того PyCharm **окончит вашу пустую строку апострофом** (т.е. сделает то, что вы назвали «дублированием кавычки») и в следующей строке кода для вас приготовит новую пару кавычек с курсором между ними, чтобы вы сразу могли писать продолжение вашей (пустой) строки:

   ```
   headers = (''
              '')
   ```

---

*Примечание:*

Представите себе, что PyCharm бы этого не сделал и ваш код бы выглядел так, как вы хотели:

```
headers = '
          что-то бы вы здесь, вероятно, написали'
```

И затем (может быть) вы бы здесь, на Stack Overflow на русском, поставили вопрос
**«Почему мой код выдает ошибку?»** ;-)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Сергей, не стоит. Вы можете «принять» мой ответ (клик на галочку возле него), когда он был для вас полезным. См. [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)